# Strange Swap behaviour on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, swap

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 machine with an application (OsTicket) Apache+PHP+MySQL.

The VM has a Total of 12GB of RAM. Only 4GB is used but I have SWAP at 100%. 
If I launch: swapoff -a && swapon -a to empty the swap partition, after a couple of Hour, the used swap reaches again 100%.
I've also tried to change the vm.swappiness parameter but no change has happened.

This is my actual state:

```
root@osticket# free -m

             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached

Mem:         12017       8310       3706         33         33        338

-/+ buffers/cache:       7939       4077

Swap:         3061          0       3061


root@osticket:~# cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness

10
```

I've also found a script that show me the processes that have swapped and how many swap each of them are using:

Overall swap used: 3134772 kB

```
kB pid name
51332 1011 mysqld
35180 12641 php
32476 14498 php
30920 10373 php
26696 12384 php
26688 10904 php
25824 20956 php ........ ........
```

Any ideas?

---

This is thr output of the command you have suggested.

```
root@osticket:~# vmstat -Sm 10
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st

 1  0   3210   6640     23    221    0    0    30    55   13   13  1  0 99  0  0

 0  0   3210   6640     23    221    0    0     1    95  109  196  0  0 100  0  0

 0  0   3210   6639     23    221    0    0     0     1   73  129  0  0 100  0  0

 0  0   3210   6647     23    221    0    0     0     7  567  761  0  1 99  0  0

 0  0   3210   6573     24    222    0    0    16   119  316  404  1  1 98  0  0

 0  0   3210   6485     24    277    0    0  5355   260 1558 2484  3  1 94  1  0

 0  0   3210   6534     25    308    0    0  2954   679 1204 1836  5  1 92  1  0

 0  0   3210   6534     25    308    0    0     0    92   86  128  0  0 100  0  0

 0  0   3210   6534     25    308    0    0     0    11   84  129  0  0 100  0  0

 0  0   3210   6534     25    308    0    0     0     1  140  229  0  0 100  0  0

 0  0   3210   6534     25    308    0    0     0     1   88  132  0  0 100  0  0

 1  0   3210   6524     25    308    0    0    62     1  233  196  1  0 99  0  0

 0  0   3210   6523     25    319    0    0  1088   101  290  441  1  0 97  1  0

 0  0   3210   6522     25    319    0    0     0    58   94  156  0  0 100  0  0

 0  0   3210   6522     25    319    0    0     0    45  111  177  0  0 100  0  0

 0  0   3210   6522     25    319    0    0     0     0  516  703  0  0 99  0  0

 0  0   3210   6522     25    319    0    0     0     6   73  124  0  0 100  0  0

 0  0   3210   6522     25    319    0    0     0     1   74  126  0  0 100  0  0

 0  0   3210   6521     25    319    0    0     0     2  118  189  0  0 100  0  0
```

Comment: Do you have any concrete reason to think that the kernel is doing something wrong? Have you measuread excessive paging operations, excessive I/O operations or some other performance counter out of expected range?

Comment: I don't know how to measure exceddive paging operations or the I/O.

Comment: I don't know how to measure exceddive paging operations or the I/O.
About the global performances, the WEB application doesn't seems to be affected by this strange behaviour and respond almost fast.

Comment: For example, `vmstat -w -Sm 10` (omit the `-w` if you cannot set the terminal to 132 columns) will display essential statistics every 10 seconds; statistics include CPU usage (look for waiting percentage), swapping in/out, I/O blocks in/out. See `man vmstat` for more details.